# Forming partnership with Santa Claus

Tags: technological-development, flight

This coming 25th of December Santa Claus and I are going to distribute presents to all the good children from all over the world, unfortunately he do not have extra magical sleigh to spare nor willing to share his endangered magical raindeers. I was informed that on the night before Xmas I will cover Asia, Africa and Australia while he take care of America and Europe.

**Question**

What kind of technology do I have to wish for so that I won't fail Santa nor disappoint the children?

**Notes**

The technology should obey known laws of physics so kindly ignore engineering issues.

We are only giving out cash vouchers in person.

Don't ask how we profile children.

Don't ask how we break into houses but each house will probably take us within a minute to do our job.

Don't ask for cloning machine.

Don't ask why I do it.

Comment below if there is any doubt, or do you suggest I should turn him down(effort needed to convince me).

Comment: Erm... who is doing Africa? His niece? And can email be used?

Comment: @Bookeater: oopsie daisy

Comment: One word. Fedex. That or Quantum.

Answer (score 0):

**Earn money from home. Fast:** Santa Claus is maybe in shady business. Being you I would not accept the offer, especially if there are some entrance fees in order to start the job itself.

Because Santa Claus knows very well, that at some years, [he can stay at home](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/13521/2071) and everything will take care of itself, because no one was good enough to get presents, while no one was naughty enough to get coal.

Being you, I would deliver coal to Santa Clause's socks. Because he starts some naughty naughty business