# Can I use my Earth changing invention to help out Santa?

Tags: post-scarcity, santa-claus

Lets face it, my [Earth changing invention](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=my%20earth%20changing%20invention) is pretty awesome. It can change [anything into anything](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/concealing-my-earth-changing-invention), I've used it to build a [business empire](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29330/my-earth-changing-invention-how-can-i-hire-the-people-i-need) and I've got my own ['north pole'](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/psychology-and-sociology-in-my-earth-changing-underwater-community). While I haven't been able to use this device to [avoid NORAD](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30472/can-i-use-my-earth-changing-invention-to-hide-in-orbit) or [end world hunger](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/if-i-reveal-my-earth-changing-invention-suddenly-will-the-energy-material-or-fo) (yet), I still think that this festive period I should use it to do some good.

Naturally I've contacted the [big man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus) beforehand, and Santa is onboard with my plan to bring some festive cheer this holiday season.

My device can change any form of matter or energy into presents, and can be used for unlimited delta-v manoeuvres. It can also be assumed that my Massive Intellect can create any number of robotic factories (Mecha-Elves) or airborne delivery drones (Reindeer-Drones) with which to deliver said presents. The presents can be made anywhere, and the drones can be deployed at any time.

My question is this:

**Is it possible to deliver a single undisclosed present weighing roughly 1 kg to 80% of the population of the Earth without causing mass panic or having my earth changing invention discovered??**

*Please note:* The present doesn't have to be placed directly under the tree, but you get bonus points if you can manage it. My Device must be able to completely enclose material to be transmuted within a set of emitters (like a 3d printer) but the emitters themselves can be mobile, and my device is capable of transmuting a kg of matter from one form to another as fast as required, but with a hum that becomes louder the more rapidly the matter is to be transmuted (1 minute/kg is silent, 1 seconds/kg is like a large washing machine, 1ms/kg is similar to a light jet engine).

You may also assume that Santa has informed me to which children (large or small) coal should be delivered.

Comment: How does it enable unlimited delta-V maneuvers?

Comment: Essentially by letting me create high energy material at one end of a tube, then reabsorbing it at the other end of the tube. That violates the conservation of momentum and gives me a flawless and powerful reactionless drive. See [here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30472/can-i-use-my-earth-changing-invention-to-hide-in-orbit?lq=1).

Comment: Violating the conservation of momentum?  I think the phrase "Earth changing invention" may be too conservative of a name.  You should come up with something that gives it some proper credit.  "Universe shatterer" comes to mind =)

Comment: @CortAmmon: Like I said: It's a pretty awesome piece of kit. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, *you* won't be blamed. Just stick to the schedule.

Just delivering the presents [may produce undesirable consequences](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31482/santa-exists-how-do-we-react), so panic can't be excluded (someone entered in our house while we were sleeping!).

You can easily place the facturated present inbetween the emitters but, do you also need those emitters at the final location (eg. near the tree)? In that case you will need some kind of teletransportation/wormhole. Albeit your drones could deliver it *near* the house, they won't be able to *enter* it without violence (such as breaking a window glass).

Existence of a tree would actually help you, since you could monitor (eg. by scanning in the infrared range) the living beings in the houses, when waiting the right time in which there are no witness awake (be careful with cameras, though) and the tree would serve to pinpoint the target location.

In any case, I don't think anyone would conclude that you had such invention. You need to be careful with the energy though. Either you use loads of energy from that place (which would be very noticeable) or you move loads of material (1Kg/person) to a near location.

Answer (score 0):

Work with big-box stores. Publish plans online for free of a device which can deliver toys easily and cheaply and is virtually free to construct. The work with the CEOs of these companies (in secret) to have them fake-construct these devices and deliver, for free, toys (of which maybe you supplied half?) to the world's population. This way, these corporations come out looking like really charitable organizations and none of this comes back on you wondering how it was done.